# I have to create a query that check before inserting if the booking dates don't overlap

Tags: sql, database, insert, checkout, checkin

I have a Booking table composed by these attributes:
Booking(ID, checkIn, checkOut)

- ID bigint NOT NULL,
- checkIn timestamp(0) NOT NULL,
- checkOut timestamp(0) NOT NULL,
- primary key(ID)

timestamp(0) datatype is something like this: '2022-12-31 23:59:59'.

and I need to create an INSERT query that checks before inserting if it doesn't exist another query overlapping those checkIn/checkOut dates.

For example I already have in my db this tuple:
(1, '2022-12-03 23:59:59', '2022-12-07 23:59:59')

If I insert this tuple (2, '2022-12-04 23:59:59', '2022-12-06 23:59:59') there are no problems for the DB, because ID is unique, but I cannot have two bookings in the iteraval from 12/04 - 12/06

This expression checks if two interval don't overlap
(checkIn1 <= checkOut2) and (checkOut1 >= checkIn2)

I'm using PostgreSQL.

Thank you very much

Comment: You need to provide us with a lot more information about your database and your schema, including what you have tried so far, before we can provide an answer. SO is not here to solve homework.

Comment: What DB server are you using?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've just updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a temporary table and enter the data or rows in that table first.

```
CREATE TABLE Table2
(ID bigint PRIMARY KEY,
checkin timestamp(0) NOT NULL, 
checkout timestamp(0) NOT NULL);
    
INSERT INTO Table2
(ID, checkin, checkout)
VALUES
(2, '2022-12-04 23:59:59', '2022-12-06 23:59:59'),
(3, '2022-12-08 23:59:59', '2022-12-09 23:59:59');
```

Now you can use this table to insert the data in to the Original table using the `JOIN` clause:

```
INSERT INTO Booking (id, checkin, checkout)
SELECT t2.* 
FROM Table2 t2
LEFT JOIN Booking t3
ON t2.id <> t3.id AND (t3.checkin > t2.checkout OR t3.checkout < t2.checkin)
WHERE t3.id IS NOT NULL;
```

[db fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a758691e929a0adbce58df19867fb174)

Comment: OMFGTYSM . This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a constraint on CHECKING and CHECKOUT values, this will allow only one unique set to be inserted, the next insertion with duplicate data will fail:

```
ALTER TABLE BOOKING ADD CONSTRAINT const_BOOKING UNIQUE (CHECKIN, CHECKOUT)
```

[Test in fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=25ee4c48bfc4376b5755261c35a25c72)

[image]

More about constraint [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS)

Comment: I'm sorry Hana, but that's not what I mean, of course I cannot insert two dates who are the same, the problem is that if I already have a booking (1, 'May 5', 'May 9'), I couldn't insert something like this (2, 'May 6', 'May 8'), because the "Flight" it's already booked in those dates.